# Standard references on meanings of colors

Tags: interpretation

I was wondering about the [physics of color](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/483106/database-of-color-emissions), and now am interested in finding out if there are any *standard* resources on the meanings or appearances of colors.

For example, color [associations](https://www.ancient.eu/article/999/color-in-ancient-egypt/) in mythology or folklore of the rainbow.

I know in the zodiac there are colors mapped to the specific stones, that would be an example like I am looking for. What google brings about however is a bunch of stuff on the psychology of color saying 'red is for danger or vibrance' etc., but there is no reference on where they are getting these features/observations from. I would like to find religious/mythological/folkloric references mentioning specific colors, like how earth/wind/fire/water are a thing of 4, or the 5 colors in China, that type of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ellen Conroy *The Symbolism of Color*](https://ia802901.us.archive.org/5/items/symbolismofcolou00conriala/symbolismofcolou00conriala.pdf) (1921) is a popular book on the topic and has been reissued.
A more serious approach would be [Marshall Sahlins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshall_Sahlins) (1976) *Colors and Cultures*,  Semiotica, Vol.16, p.1–22. This leads into the contemporary debate about naming/distinguishing colors which has a long history. In a nutshell: it is culturally relativistic, so only 'field studies' or concrete sources can present the variants of color symbolism.

[Michel_Pastoureau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Pastoureau), a medievist, has a number of books on colors in the (medieval) Western world, some of them available only in French. I just saw (in google books) another book with the title *The Symbolism of Color* by Faber Birren (1988).

I think the topic fascinating when you step beyond a naive universalism.